# Using a Rode NGT 2 and Zoom h4n pro and very flat quality. Solutions?

Tags: microphone, zoom, rode

I've been testing my new Rode NGT 2 with my Zoom H4N Pro. My girlfriend is a professional singer so mainly testing with her singing. The Rode NGT 2 seems ridiculously flat and untextured compared with the Zoom's on-board recording. Yes the Zoom is recording in stereo, but the Rode is ridiculously poor, about what you get when recording with a smart phone. I tried initially with the phantom power from the Zoom, and then with a battery, which improved things a little, but not to a level that I would call good. We're both confused that a microphone that is meant to be suitable for basic pro uses should be so so poor.

Does anyone know if the NGT 2 and the H4N Pro is a bad pairing, and is there a work-around?

Is it surprising that it should sound so flat?

Answer (score 1):

The NTG2 needs phantom or battery power to begin with. But it is not suitable for recording music as it has a super cardioid polar pattern, which means it's highly directional if your off axis even slightly you will get poor pick up. Shotgun mics are for broadcast and location sound. Moreover the NTG2 is not a professional mic, the NTG3 and NTG8 are Rode's Pro mic range, but you don't want them either as they are media type mics not intended for music.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be using a large capsule mic with a pop-shield for this application, not a super-cardioid shotgun mic. Also, ensure that you record with adequate headroom and don't push the level into the limiter on the H4N. The NTG2 is the wrong mic for this application. If you are looking at a Rode mic, you should be looking at an NT2A or TLM103. Obviously U87 would be good but they are very pricey.